# How to grab Bluehost mail using python

Tags: python, email, bluehost

Is there any way to programmatically fetch my Bluehost email (name@domain.com) using Python? There are certain emails that I want to grab the text of, so I would want to filter the emails as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How hard is it to build an Email client? - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647487/how-hard-is-it-to-build-an-email-client-python)

Comment: Read the documentation [pop3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/poplib.html), [imap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html), and [email](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html).

Comment: The problem is that Bluehost blocks any ports under 1000, so I can't use pop3, imap, etc. The only ports that it doesn't block is 80 and 443, which are http and https port, respectively. So is it possible to fetch email using either of these ports?